# Unix finding the mean of two files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a folder called reviews_folder which contains lots of files such as hotel_188976.dat or hotel_234566.dat.
I am trying to write a script that uses grep -c to find how many times each hotel_*.dat has "Overall" in it but i only want to do it for two files in reviews_folder.

I currently have this in my script called script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -c "Overall" reviews_folder/hotel_*.dat
```

but this does it for all files in reviews_folder and I only want it for two specific file
e.g when I type in this to bash:

```
./script1.sh hotel_1 hotel_2
```

I want the script1 to find number of "Overall" comes up in hotel_1 and hotel_2.

script1.sh and reviews_folder and in the same folder but within reviews_folder is many files of hotel_*.dat.

Is it possible to help me on my current script1.sh

Answer (score 0):

.How about

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 $2|grep -c "Overall"
```

cat concatenates the two files into one single stream on stdout which can be used for grepping.

Should be called with the two named files as arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -c "Overall" "$1".dat "$2".dat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to support an arbitrary number of call parameters:

#!/bin/bash

```
for i in "$@"; do
  grep "Overall" reviews_folder/"$i".dat
done
```